# why is the name property not being displayed

Tags: reactjs

I have a state that has an array of objects each object has a name property, I created a function to loop over the array and display the name property  of each object  when I call the function there is nothing on the screen why is that I am 100% sure the function is working I `console.log` the objects and name Property it's there

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Products extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showItems = this.showItems.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      products: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Espresso',
          price: 5.5,
          summary: 'Galão, grinder mocha',
          show: true,
          showText: false,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Americano',
          price: 10.5,
          summary: 'Galão, grinder mocha',
          show: true,
          showText: false,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Latte',
          price: 7.5,
          summary: 'Galão, grinder mocha',
          show: true,
          showText: false,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'Flat white ',
          price: 3.5,
          summary: 'Galão, grinder mocha',
          show: true,
          showText: false,
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'Mocha',
          price: 15,
          summary: 'Galão, grinder mocha',
          show: true,
          showText: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  showItems() {
    this.state.products.map((el) => {
      return <div>{el.name}</div>;
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="products">
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <div className="items">{this.showItems()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Products;
```

[here is a screenshot of the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqUmO.png)

Comment: You're missing a return from `showItems`. You need `return this.state.products ...`

Comment: thank u so much i completely forgot about it can u give me  an advice?  is there a way to make me remember that kinda of stuff or coding in general since i can't code everyday and i forget these little details too often

Comment: You can install a linter or use an IDE that can give you smart insights about your code (WebStorm is one such IDE). But I don't think anything can tell you about this exact problem that you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `JS code` into your html as `JSX`. Hence you use map function to iterate and generate your element as below:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="products">
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <div className="items">
          {this.state.products.map((el) => {
            return <div>{el.name}</div>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: i wanted to do that in a seprate function

Comment: oh in that case you can follow @JohnnyCapreano comments that is: including return statement.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the return statement in my `showItems()` function

```
  return  this.state.products.map((el) => {
      return <div>{el.name}</div>;
    });`
```

Comment: thx @Asgar  how did u format the code

Comment: When editing a question or answer there is a code icon in the toolbar, alternatively you can use the "backtick" ( ` )... one backtick around text will make in-line code, 3 wrapped around will give you a codeblock, See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/15291770)